# Como remover espaço do valor JSON (String) em C#?

Tags: c#, json, replace

Tenho o seguinte JSON armazenado numa variável String:

```
{"novosPedidos":[],"pedidos":[{"Apagar":" 633.56"}]}
```

O valor do "Apagar" contém um espaço o qual eu preciso remover.

Tentei usar o método Replace() porém não obtive o resultado esperado:

```
var newJson = json.Replace(":\" ", ":\"");
```

O resultado do valor de "Apagar" do newJson permaneceu inalterado (com espaço).

Também tentei usar Replace() substituindo somente espaço, porém não funcionou:

```
var newJson = json.Replace(" ", "");
```

Eu fiz um teste no IdeOne: https://ideone.com/W6rAqE

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Copiei EXATAMENTE o JSON Original e apareceu um caractér estranho no lugar do espaço. Não consegui identificar o que seja. Como resolver?

Comment: Aqui está funcionando [https://ideone.com/ddaSu6](https://ideone.com/ddaSu6).

Comment: Eu copiei a String direto do JSON original e fiz um teste no IdeOne. O engraçado que lá ao invés de estar mostrando um espaço vazio, está constando um "ponto" destacado. Será que algum tipo de quebra? https://ideone.com/W6rAqE

Comment: Pq não usa o `var newJson = json.Replace(" ", "");`?

Comment: Cypher, veja o exemplo aqui que montei - https://ideone.com/W6rAqE por algum motivo esta vindo algum caracter especial estranho que não estou sabendo identificar. Ali não está contendo espaço realmente...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O caractere que você está tentando substituir não é um espaço, mas sim um [**espaço rígido**](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espa%C3%A7o_r%C3%ADgido) (*non-breaking space*).

Sendo assim, basta dar o replace pelo seu código Unicode (\u00A0):

```
var newJson = json.Replace(":\"\u00A0", ":\"");
```

Para descobrir o valor decimal do caractere, basta convertê-lo:

```
Console.WriteLine((int)(' '));
```

O resultado é 160, que representa o **espaço rígido** na tabela ASCII.

Você também conseguirá remover esse espaço usando Regex:

```
Regex.Replace(json, @"[:][""]\s+", ":\"");
```

Teste: https://ideone.com/TweHsH

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta em detalhes amigo, solução perfeita.